# update one checkbox when clicking another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have two checkboxes for capturing the delivery/collection methods.

Checkbox 1 visible for desktop:

```
<input type="radio" value="COLLECTION" id="coldelcheck1" name="coldelcheck1" 
class="icheck" checked onclick="coldel_pref()"  onchange="coldel_pref()" >
<input type="radio" value="DELIVERY" id="coldelcheck1" name="coldelcheck1" 
class="icheck" checked onclick="coldel_pref()"  onchange="coldel_pref()" >
```

Checkbox 2 visible for mobile:

```
<input type="radio" value="COLLECTION" id="coldelcheck2" name="coldelcheck2" 
class="icheck" checked onclick="coldel_pref()"  onchange="coldel_pref()" >
<input type="radio" value="DELIVERY" id="coldelcheck2" name="coldelcheck2" 
class="icheck" checked onclick="coldel_pref()"  onchange="coldel_pref()" >
```

If the user clicks the desktop version then I want the corresponding hidden mobile value to checked and vice versa. If delivery on desktop is checked then I want the delivery on mobile to be checked. How can I do this using jquery/javascript?

Comment: What have you tried @sidneyuk? Remember, StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. You may want to find out how to make a [minimal, complete, and verifiable question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: hi @AJFarmar, i tried using the onchange/onlick triggers but these do not even get called.

Comment: Please edit your question instead of writing more information in comments. Furthermore, please write the code you use so we can read it properly. Have you read how to make a [minimal, complete, and verifiable question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) yet?

Comment: @sidneyuk Add your JS code so we can take a look. Also, if you know how to solve this, why are you asking "how do I do this"? It's good that you aren't getting stuck on a potentially wrong approach, but the relevant question here is, why aren't the onchange handlers called.

Comment: I think I found the problem. If `coldel_pref()` is toggling the values, it'll end up changing them (onclick), then changing them right back (onchange). You'll want to remove the onclicks.

Comment: hi i tried removing the onclick. it did not work. for now i just have a simple alter call to check if its calling the function

Comment: function coldel_pref() {
  alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
    }

Comment: @sidneyuk Please edit your question instead of posting updates in comments - it's far more helpful and easily-formatted there. You do this by pressing the `edit` button directly bellow the `jquery` tag on your question.

Comment: hi all, thanks for your help. first question so struggling to know what to do. i want to put a freeze on the question and do some more research, i don't even know how to do that,

Comment: Hi @Philicare, your second shorter version seems to be what i want,  have taken your suggestions and will add it to my code. looks good. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest way (not very good though -  not a good pratice to have same ids).

Please note the `this` as first argument of function **calls**.

```js
function  coldel_pref(theRadio){

  var theOtherId = theRadio.id == 'coldelcheck1' ? '2' : '1';

  var theOtherDomId = "coldelcheck"+theOtherId;

  var theOtherSelector = 'input#'+theOtherDomId+'[type="radio"][value="'+theRadio.value+'"]';

  var e = document
            .querySelector(theOtherSelector)
            .checked = true;

}
```

```html
<table border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5"><tr><th>Desktop</th><th>Mobile</th></tr><tr><td>
<input type="radio" value="COLLECTION" 
       id="coldelcheck1" name="coldelcheck1" class="icheck" checked 
       onclick="coldel_pref(this)"  onchange="coldel_pref(this)" /><input type="radio" value="DELIVERY" id="coldelcheck1" name="coldelcheck1" class="icheck" checked onclick="coldel_pref(this)"  onchange="coldel_pref(this)" /></td><td>
<input type="radio" value="COLLECTION" 
       id="coldelcheck2" name="coldelcheck2" class="icheck" checked 
       onclick="coldel_pref(this)"  onchange="coldel_pref(this)" /><input type="radio" value="DELIVERY" id="coldelcheck2" name="coldelcheck2" class="icheck" checked onclick="coldel_pref(this)"  onchange="coldel_pref(this)" /></td></tr>
</table>
```

A better and shorter one?

```js
  function cpref(theRadio)
  {

    var specs = theRadio.id.split('-');

    specs[1] = specs[1] == 'mobile' ? 'desktop' : 'mobile';

    document.getElementById(specs.join('-')).checked = true ;

  }
```

```html
<table border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5"><tr><th>Desktop</th><th>Mobile</th></tr><tr><td>

<input type="radio" value="COLLECTION" 
       id="rad-desktop-1" name="coldelcheck1" class="icheck"
       onclick="cpref(this)"  onchange="cpref(this)" />

<input type="radio" value="DELIVERY" 
       id="rad-desktop-2" name="coldelcheck1" class="icheck" 
       onclick="cpref(this)"  onchange="cpref(this)" /></td><td>

<input type="radio" value="COLLECTION" 
       id="rad-mobile-1" name="coldelcheck2" class="icheck"
       onclick="cpref(this)"  onchange="cpref(this)" />

<input type="radio" value="DELIVERY" 
       id="rad-mobile-2" name="coldelcheck2" class="icheck"
       onclick="cpref(this)"  onchange="cpref(this)" /></td></tr>

</table>
```